# transform (x,y,z) coordinate from kinect to /map frame using tf

Tags: ros, opencv, quaternion, static-transform-publisher, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm tracking an object using a kinect and trying to publish the tf transform of that object in a "/map frame. I'm able to return the object's x, y and depth data using OpenCV. However, I'm struggling with the tf stuff. I've written a function which is meant to update the transform

```
void updatetransform(double x, double y, double z)
{
     r = -1.5708;
     p = 0;
     y = -3.1415;

   static tf::TransformBroadcaster br;  

  transform.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(x, y, z));
  quaternion.setRPY(r,p,y);  //where r p y are fixed 
  transform.setRotation(quaternion);
     
  br.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(transform, ros::Time::now(), "kinect2_ir_optical_frame","drone/base_link"));
  
  ROS_INFO("Sent Drone Transform at %f %f %f", x, y, z);

}
```

and in my launch file

```
<launch>
  <node name = "Drone_Detector" pkg="detector" type="detect_drone" output="screen" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="baselink" args="0 0 1 -1.5708 0 -1.5708 /map /kinect2_link 50" />
</launch>
```

But when I run Rviz, using "/map" as a fixed frame, the drone/base_link tf isn't shown in the screen. I've attached a picture of what it looks like at this [link](https://imgur.com/a/MZEmV). My x,y and depth values are okay from what the kinect but the transform is wrong. Am I doing something wrong here?

Also here's my tf_tree which looks about right to me. [Link here](https://imgur.com/a/hPuDq)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259633/transform-(x,y,z)-coordinate-from-kinect-to-/map-frame-using-tf/) by [cluelessnigerian](https://answers.ros.org/users/28510/cluelessnigerian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't see any obvious problems with the code, and it seems from your rviz screenshot that the `base/drone_link` is indeed present (I suspect it to be at the end of the yellow line.) Can you expand up the TF ->  Frames tree and inspect the x y and z of the `base/drone_link` transform to confirm that they are what you expect them to be?

Perhaps it's a good idea to first test the `updateTransform` function with a know x y and z.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cluelessnigerian](https://answers.ros.org/users/28510/cluelessnigerian/) on 2017-04-20**:
I took your advice and took a look at TF -> Frames. The X,Y,Z values in the relative position are about right for `drone/base_link`. [Link Here](https://imgur.com/a/K33I2).However, I'm not quite sure if I understand the output of the remaining values (orientation etc) so I'm not sure how to interpret

**Comment by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) on 2017-04-20**:
It seems to me that you don't see the transform on the screen simply because it is too large. the Y and Z values of -438 and -323 indicate that the frame will be *very* far away, and not in the default view. If you zoom out very far it should show up. I'm not sure I understand what the problem is.

**Comment by [cluelessnigerian](https://answers.ros.org/users/28510/cluelessnigerian/) on 2017-04-20**:
I think I'm probably not calculating the transform properly. -438 and -323 are actual pixel positions of the object I'm tracking from the kinect. Surely there must be a way to transform them into a frame that actually shows up within the map frame.